# How did Konami games recognize the famous cheat code?

Tags: nes, snes

The famous [Konami cheat code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konami_Code) is the sequence

```
up, up, down, down, left, right, left, right, B, A
```

*What original algorithm was used to detect that the code was entered?*  I can think of two possible ways:

1. Keep an array of the last button presses.  When a new button is pressed, add it to the array and check for a matching sequence.
2. Use a finite state machine.  When a new button is pressed, determine the next state based on the current state and which button was just pressed.

Comment: Or just a counter that holds the number of correct button presses in the sequence.

Comment: Or a sequence of "get next button"; if wrong one, branch back to start of loop, else continue.

Comment: @traal that *is* a state machine

Comment: it was kind of an obvious cheat code, if you ask me : )

Answer (score 4):

Of course, there are many ways in which this could be implemented. So the question is most interesting if we consider the earliest usage for Gradius on the NES. For an 8-bit console like the NES, the programmer would take into account both execution and space efficiency.

The algorithm is trivially implemented using only two bytes of RAM and some simple bitwise shift and OR operations. This would seem appropriately efficient for the NES.

The NES has 4 directions so Up, Down, Left, and Right are each represented by 2 bits. This means the the full sequence corresponding to UUDDLRLR can be stored in two bytes. So in the ROM we have the value for that sequence and we need to OCCASIONALLY compare that known sequence with the last 8 directional inputs to see if it matches. The last 8 inputs would be stored in the 2 bytes of RAM, using shift and OR to remove the oldest and add the newest each time there is a new input. It's basically a 16 bit array, and we are adding the newest 2-bits at one end while removing the oldest 2-bits at the other end using our shift + OR operations.

The comparison between the last 8 inputs and the secret code in ROM is only required when the user presses "A" after having pressed "B". This is best described as a really simple Finite State Machine having only two states.

- State 'B': activate when the input is B.
- State 'Check': If State 'B' is active, and input is A, then activate.

So when you activate the 'Check' state, you just need to compare the two bytes representing the last 8 direction inputs with the secret ROM code for UUDDLRLR. If it matches, then the code checks and you grant the cheat/reward.

There is only a little additional logic for resetting  directional input buffer to $0000 after an A input, and for toggling whether State 'B' is active or not. You might use an additional single-byte variable for that, or you might save memory space by using some branching.

All said, it can be done this way with little execution overhead and very little RAM, which is good for the NES. And you were on the right track, but I think the solution is really a combination of a simple array for the directions and a simple FSM for the A/B buttons.